# python and regression analysis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to do regression analysis in python, but there are errors. Please help me.

I already imported modules below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%pylab
```

and I got data like below:

```
data=pd.read_csv('file.csv',names['storedate','amount','location'])
```

then I defined x and y like below:

```
x=data['amount']
y=data['location']
```

and I tried to do the code below
    x = sm.add_constant(x, prepend=False)

but here is an first error like below:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

and I also got an error with the code below:

```
model = sm.OLS(y,x)
results = model.fit()
```

the message is:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error message "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" appears, because x and y are not numpy arrays.  Use

```
x = np.array(data['amount'])
y = np.array(data['location'])
```

instead of your current definition of x and y.